# Three.js - BufferGeometry warning Render count or primcount is 0 when no index is specify

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create a BufferGeometry without setting the indices.
(As written [here](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry), in this case the renderer assumes that each three contiguous positions represent a single triangle), but I get the warning *Render count or primcount is 0* and no geometry is shown.
What am I doing wrong?

Here following the code to reproduce the issue.

```
var buffGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffGeometry.attributes =
{
    position:
    {
        itemSize: 3, array: new Float32Array([10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0]),
        numItems: 18    
    }
};

indexArray = new Uint32Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

< !--it works adding the index array with the following line-- >
// buffGeometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indexArray, 1));

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );       
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(buffGeometry, material);    
scene.add(mesh);
```

three.js r77

([Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An48nRAUUcfbhiTuAYLUceQ-ApJ4) the complete sample)

Comment: A JsFiddle would be nice to debugging. But I'm pretty sure that you are not supposed to set the attributes directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation here:
http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry

In short, you're not supposed to set the `attribute` property directly.
Instead, you're supposed to create a `THREE.BufferAttribute` and then add it to the geometry by calling `.addAttribute('position', bufferAttribute)`

EDIT: Not sure how `setIndex` work, does it actually render anything or not crash?

Comment: EDIT: in the latest release _setIndex_ has replaced the .addAttribute('index', bufferAttribute)

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was receiving this warning when using this code, which was working completely fine:

```js
  const curveMesh = new THREE.Mesh()
  let curve

  allCoords.forEach(coords => {
    curve = new Curve(coords, material, step)
    curveMesh.add(curve.mesh)
    curveMesh.add(curve.meshOrigin)
    curveMesh.add(curve.meshDestination)
  })

  rootMesh.add(curveMesh)
```

When I replaced it with this line, it started to not see the warning anymore `[.WebGL-0x7fe61b026400]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.`

```js
// please notice here is now Group!
  const curveMesh = new THREE.Group()
  let curve

  allCoords.forEach(coords => {
    curve = new Curve(coords, material, step)
    curveMesh.add(curve.mesh)
    curveMesh.add(curve.meshOrigin)
    curveMesh.add(curve.meshDestination)
  })

  rootMesh.add(curveMesh)
```